# how to use class like names in C when invoking methods

Tags: c, class, namespaces, global

## console.c

```
void write(const char* string) {
   // ...
}
```

## console.h

```
void write(const char* string);
```

## myapp.c

```
write("Hello world.\n");
```

But for clarity I do not want to use just `write()`... but instead use something like `console.write()` or `Console.write()`. Is this possible?

I do not really want to use `console_write()`, for no other reason than asthetics.

## background

I am a beginner in C, but proficient in C#. This is something I thought of when doing a basic tutorial on OS development, in which I am using a cross compiler better suited for C development. Infact I would prefer to do this in C if it was possible and not mix with C++.

Comment: Why not use `C++` directly?

Comment: You should really not do this for asthetic reasons only. It's better to use each programming language the way it most naturally handles itself. If you assign function pointers to struct, you will only create pointless boilerplate code which will serve no purpose, but will affect maintenance. In the long run, `_` is much lesser evil.

Comment: @user694733 I am beginning to agree, but I wanted to know how it could be done before deciding if it is worth it.

Comment: Other thing to notice is that, taking address of a function makes optimization much more difficult. I am no expert on the matter, but I suspect it would make inlining impossible, and harder to predict the jumps.

Answer (score 2):

You could use pointers to functions in a `struct`.

You could create e.g. a `struct console`, in which you have a pointer to a function:

```
typedef struct Console {
    void (*write)(const char*);
    //...
} Console;
```

which you later assign to the function:

```
//function declaration
void write(const char*);
//...
Console console;
console.write = &write;
console.write("writing something to console");
```

If <s>your compiler is capable of `C99` and</s> you want to skip the assignment you could make the `console` object global and assign its internals like so:

```
void write(const char*);
struct Console {
    void (*write)(const char*);
} c = { &write };
```

Because I created this first as a comment and later created an answer deleting the comment, to which @user694733 replied, I'd like to say that I agree with user694733: "It's better to use each programming language the way it most naturally handles itself." :)

Comment: Could the "assign later" part be done inside the console.c class itself, and for it to return a console struct to use without having to assign this in the calling class?

Comment: What does C99 have to do with anything of this?

Comment: @Lundin at first I wanted to use a compound literal during a quick edit answering OPs comment but changed my mind in the process and forgot to remove this, thanks :)